# Could not find Dart in your Flutter SDK. Please run 'flutter doctor' in the terminal then reload the project once all issues are resolve

Tags: flutter, macos, dart

**Could not find Dart in your Flutter SDK. Please run 'flutter doctor' in the terminal then reload the project once all issues are resolved.**

Comment: please consider question part only for question. You can remove the answer from question.

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Working

1. Delete the flutter folder
2. Downloaded the. https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos dart
3. Unzip downloaded flutter - copy to past the delete location
4. Restart the visual studio & flutter pub get